# How much time elapses during Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, agents-of-shield, time

How much total time elapsed from the beginning of *Age of Ultron* to the end?

Some possible reference points:

- Agents of SHIELD had bookend episodes, so it can't be longer than the time between the two episodes. (Is this true or is there some overlap?)
- > Hawkeye's wife is shown as very pregnant at one point, but then the baby is born before the end of the movie. The baby looks a few months old, but certainly not 1 year old. This could help calibrate time passage.

Comment: At the beginning of *Scars* (S02E20), Coulson makes mention that it's been about a week since the previous episode.

Comment: Estimating elapsed time by a baby's apparent age is rarely accurate. Day-old babies are, understandably, hardly fit for the camera, and babies shown on screen are usually considerably older than they're supposed to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**About a week.**

At the beginning of *Agents of SHIELD* s02e20 “Scars”, Coulson says:

> What's transpired over the last week is a lot to take in.

Given the matter of fact tone in which Ultron’s defeat and Theta Protocol (the deployment of a repaired Helicarrier) is discussed, we can deduce that the events of *Age of Ultron* have concluded before this episode airs.

At the end of s02e19 “The Dirty Half Dozen”, we see

> Coulson and Maria Hill discuss the location of Loki’s sceptre in Sokovia, and the then-unexplained Theta Protocol. Since *Age of Ultron* begins with the Avenger’s storming the stronghold in Sokovia for the sceptre, it follows that this episode ends before the film begins.

Coulson is only interested in the threat posed by Ultron, not what the Avengers get up to afterward. It’s possible and likely that some of the scenes at the end of the film (including the scene with Hawkeye’s baby) take place after this week has finished. So most of the film is covered in a week, but it might stretch longer than that.

---

In an interview with [the Empire podcast](http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=44188), Joss Whedon was asked when the scene with Hawkeye’s baby took place. (About the 28 minute mark) According to him, it’s at least a few months.

Comment: Good point that the ending scenes could actually be several months later- that makes a lot more sense.